# C++, concepts not working with unsigned integers as a result type?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I am playing around with `concepts` and I tried to define a `concept` which takes any `non-type parameter` and the function `isUnsignedInt` checks if the parameter is an`unsigned int`, using the `required` keyword followed by the `concept`.

The problem is, that I can pass a negative integer and there is no error message, that the type is not `unsigned int`.

Is my understanding of concepts wrong?

Currently I am working with the `gcc 9.2 compiler` and my CMake contains `add_compile_options(-fconcepts)`, which enables `concepts`.

Code:

```
template<auto a>
concept special = requires(){
    {a} -> unsigned int;
};

template<auto a> requires special<a>
constexpr auto isUnsignedInt(){
    return a;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << isUnsignedInt<-2>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-2
```

Comment: It seems like you are misusing the `->` refinement, per [this summary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) of concepts syntax. Instead of a bare `unsigned int`, maybe you need `std::same_as<unsigned int>`? Note that the page also uses `UnsignedIntegral` as an example concept (applying to types, not values).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

> ```
> {a} -> unsigned int;
> ```

Is no longer a thing in the version of concepts that C++20 will get. By all rights, it should be a compile error. But since that change was made only a few months ago at most, it's not surprising that it compiles under your compiler.

Since it's no longer valid syntax, the real question is what that used to mean. Which also explains why they removed it.

That syntax didn't mean "this expression is the exact type `unsigned int`". It meant "this expression is *implicitly convertible to* the type `unsigned int`". Obviously `int` is implicitly convertible to `unsigned int`, which is why the concept passes for a negative number.

The fact that you expected it to mean "the same" even though it doesn't is precisely why it was removed. So you have to spell it out explicitly: `{a} -> std::same_as<unsigned int>`, where `std::same_as` is the concept equivalent to the trait `std::is_same_v`. Since GCC probably doesn't include the standard library concepts yet, you'll have to write your own equivalent.

Comment: I thank you for your explanation. Does that mean, the `concept` that is useable with the compiler option is not the same concept that will be used in the std library?

Comment: @M.Mac: I don't know what you mean by that. The syntax you are using is no longer *legal syntax*; it's just that your compiler hasn't caught up to the standard. C++20 isn't done, and there may be more changes yet to come. So these things will happen.

Comment: I understand, i have to get in touch with the new syntax:)